# Why is the constructor of std::in_place_t defaulted and explicit?

Tags: c++, std, explicit, explicit-constructor, defaulted-functions

cppreference shows the following definition of `std::in_place_t`:

```
struct in_place_t {
    explicit in_place_t() = default;
};
inline constexpr std::in_place_t in_place{};
```

Why have they added an `explicit` and defaulted constructor? Why it isn't left out? What are the benefits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a type like this to only be `explicit`ly constructible, because it exists to denote a particular kind of constructor overload, in places where `{}` might reasonably be found.

Consider the following constructions

```
std::optional<DefaultConstructible> dc1({}); // dc1 == std::nullopt
std::optional<DefaultConstructible> dc2(std::in_place); // dc2 == DefaultConstructible()
```

Comment: It would be worth mentioned the technique being used in the constructor (or in more general method) overload is tag dispatching.

Answer (score 4):

If you leave out the constructor it will not be `explicit`. If you don't `= default` it it will not be *trivial*.

So, if you want the constructor to be `explicit` and you also want it to remain trivial, what you see is the only option available.

Comment: @davidbak Thank you.

Comment: It would be good to know why it's important to have the constructor explicit and trivial in this case.

Comment: I was expecting answer like: "without `explicit` this kind of code `...` will compile and we don't what that since ... ". Current version can be rephrased to: "it is like it is", so I don't get it why it so highly voted. I think everyone understand what `explicit` and `default` do here, question was: why?